# Redirect URL abc.net/x/y#z to abc.net/ using Apache Redirect module

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a URL of form abc.net/x/y#z to abc.net/

Currently if I give the rewrite rule as below -
RewriteRule "^x/y" "/" [R=301,L,NE]

The end result is abc.com/#z
Is there a better way to handle it?

I want to basically remove the string following #